# Why aspnet_isapi.dll still exists in iis7?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

As far as i know asp.net has been integrated with IIS.

That is to say, asp.net runtime is always hosted in IIS7 no matter the incoming request is.
ie. An `.aspx` request or others static files request like `.html` or `.jpg`.

We know that in IIS6, `aspnet_isapi.dll` will be loaded to create asp.net runtime and run asp.net only when requests such as `.aspx`,`.ashx` arrive.

Now that asp.net has been integrated with IIS7 in "Integrated Mode" what's the usage of `aspnet_isapi.dll`? Is it the reason why we can still see aspnet_isapi.dll in iis7 is compatibility ?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, it's only for classic mode.

With classic pipeline mode the ASP.NET is plugged into the IIS request processing pipeline as an ISAPI extension - exactly the same way as it was in IIS 6. In fact, if you open %WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config file and locate the  section inside of it you can see how IIS is configured to map ASP.NET specific requests to the aspnet_isapi.dll:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
  ...
  <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" 
       path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" 
       modules="IsapiModule" 
       scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
       preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  ...
</handlers>
```

Notice the preCondition attribute for the handler mapping. Among other things this attribute is set to classicMode, which ensures that this handler mapping only takes effect when the application pool is configured to run in classic mode.